Generalization of pairs trading to portfolios?
Standard pairs trading only trades one security against another.
In principle, nothing is stopping one from trading a portfolio of N stocks. There must be work on this? If so, can you point me to any references on portfolio-based pairs trading?

Hi: no one responded possibly because the question is not that clear. Do you mean carrying multiple pairs as a portfolio or trading a basket of stocks against one stock say ? Either way, there's no magic or secret sauce ( atleast that I'm aware of ) when doing those things which may also be another reason why no one responded.

Agree, This is what many people do under the rubric of quant long/short or StatArb trading. Instead of 2 carefully chosen stocks paired against each other, you have two portfolios one long one short that have been carefully constructed to be different on some dimensions you think generate return differences but similar on some risk dimensions that you want to cancel out. Multi-factor would be another name for this very general approach.
